# Cannot return error message from prepared statement php

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement which works and allows me to enter information into the table as required. However I'm not getting any return for the if-not part of the statement.
I'd like the error message to appear on the website if the information is not input into the table for example if I have a duplicate entry it will not work with my table but I just get the else{} part and booking has been registered when in fact the table has not changed.

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)){
  
  echo "
  <div class='registered'>
  Cannot book same activity twice
  </div>";

 } else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $activityID, $db_id, $date_of_activity, $number_of_tickets);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  echo "<div class='registered'>
  <h2>Your booking has now been registered<h2>
  </div>
  ";
}
```

Comment: Try this `if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){ echo "your message ";}` and search for form validation using php

Comment: I'm still getting "booking has been registered" when I should get "cannot book"

Comment: You dont do validating for in coming data example : `if(empty($activityID)){ echo "field is empty";}` if you dont validate or check for values coming from html form it will insert data null or empty on your database setup. Again search for form validation using php. see this example scrol down to Create page https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php

Comment: Remove all these `if` statements and enable proper error reporting instead.

Answer (score -2):

You are only checking if you're prepared statement can be created... you are not actually executing the query there.

You should check if this line actually succeeded:

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);